# I have no java home

Tags: java

so like yesterday I saw a java update and I clicked it(first mistake) and when the update was finished I went to cmd straight away and then I saw java 1.8 when I had java 11 before. I tried to download java 11 again but then when I went to cmd and typed java it showed that it couldn't open jvm.cfg. So then I went deleting all the Java related folders because of a tutorial. And then I went back t cmd and java and java -version worked but echo %JAVA_HOME% didn't. Now I can't use eclipse. If you know the problem please comment. It will really help me. Thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that you "went deleting all the Java related folders". Have you tried doing a clean install of the Java version you actually want? Then it'll either set JAVA_HOME as part of the installer, or it'll tell you where it installed itself and you can set the variable on your own.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice tutorial that looks like it was designed for an intro CS class that puts the steps pretty plainly.

[http://cis.csuohio.edu/~sschung/ESC120/GuideForInstallingSettingUpJava_1.pdf](http://cis.csuohio.edu/%7Esschung/ESC120/GuideForInstallingSettingUpJava_1.pdf)

There is a step that includes setting JAVA_HOME after you install. Basically you're going to want to do it after you install the product and at the same time you're adding your new JDK installs /bin into your PATH...

Look for these lines to set your PATH and JAVA_HOME here in environment variables:

```
1. In Control Panel -> System -> Advanced System Setting -> Environment Variables:
```

Comment: Note, attempting to give all credit where due, I tried to lookup the author and I think it's this person you can thank for the doc. https://engineering.csuohio.edu/eecs/sunnie-s-chung-college-lecturer